# Leading Zeros on ip number

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to know if an IP address is valid, but I want my method to return false if any of the 4 IP components has a leading zero, and is not `000` or `0`.

I've tried to do it in one instruction:

```
public static bool is_valid_IP(String ip) {
 try {
  return ip.Split('.')
         .ToList()
         .Where(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)<=255 && Convert.ToInt32(x)>=0  && notleadingzerocontition)
         .Count()==4;
  } catch(Exception) {
          return false;
  }
 }
```

What I need is that not leading zero condition goes true if its 000, but otherwise if the IP number contains any leading zero it goes false.

For example:

- `0` -> `true`
- `000` -> `true`
- `01` -> `false`
- `001` -> `false`
- `20` -> `true`

There are better solutions using regex patterns, but I'm practising LINQ.

Can I do this in one statement using LINQ?

Comment: any reason why you're rolling your own? is [`IPAddress.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse?view=net-5.0) not working for you? plus: _why_ don't you want to allow leading zeros?

Comment: So almost all subnet IPs like `255.255.255.0` would fail? Are you sure?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , is just a train exercise for programming im not using in a program , but thanks!

Comment: @FranzGleichmann , for example if i pass "12.34.56" ip fails, is just a programming exercise to improve coding myself with linq

Comment: ...as it should do.

Comment: "12.34.56" is one component too short.

Comment: I'd suggest writing a proper unit test first, so you have well defined values to test against _each time_. Then make it pass the test.

Comment: @Fildor true a good solution could be testing with a split and the ipAdress.tryparse, but could it be done with the linq i propose?

Comment: @HéctorSolarRuiz LINQ is a query language, not a parser. A regular expression would be a lot faster. You're trying to validate a specific string format anyway, so you need to actually check the strings. If a number is <100, does it start with `0`? What about spaces?

Comment: 'instruction' usually means hardware instruction, (or possibly CLR instruction), and that is clearly impossible. I guess you mean 'one expression' or 'one statement', or maybe 'one line'

Comment: "Doing it in one linq" is not always the best solution. Neither performancewise nor in readability. Maybe yu set this as a challenge for you - ok, then. But to train for real life coding tasks, find a solution that _works_ first. Then tweak that until you like it (and it passes your requirements in whatever you set in performance / memory footprint ... ) -- And on the way: Maybe take a step back sometimes and think about if a certain step towards your preferred implementation was worth the time spent on it.

Comment: @JonasH thanks for the correction i fixed it now. Yeah i mean statement.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the advice , just trying to do on linq way i know is worst performance but i want to practise with it , anyway i will do with regex , thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. Weird Where clause reflects the weirdness of the requirements.

```
public static bool is_valid_IP(String ip)
{
    var parts = ip.Split('.');

    return parts.Length == 4 && parts
        .Select(x => new { StringValue = x, Parsed = int.TryParse(x, out int i), IntValue = i })
        .Where(x => x.Parsed && x.IntValue <= 255 && x.IntValue >= 0 &&
            (x.StringValue[0] != '0' || x.StringValue == "0" || x.StringValue == "000"))
        .Count() == 4;
}
```

Comment: This solution takes into account cases like "1..2.3.4", where it should return false.